# Query takes 10 minutes when table variables are used versus 2 seconds when temporary table is used

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

There is an old query written by someone which uses table variables and it was running in 2-3 minutes. From last 2 weeks, it runs eternally even though the dataset size is approximately same. Hence, I am trying to optimize the script. The script runs 99.99% faster when I replace table variable with a temporary table. What is the exact reason for this? I agree that the table variable does not suit for large datasets. However in this case, the record count is in thousands. Both table variable and temporary table stores the data in tempDB, then why this difference? What could have happened in the backend where the table variable which was running in 2-3 minutes before, takes an insane amount of time now?

```
    DECLARE @test_table1 TABLE(/*some columns*/ );

    INSERT INTO @test_table1
    SELECT /*some columns*/ FROM SomeTable1
        LEFT JOIN SomeTable2
        LEFT JOIN SomeTable3
        LEFT JOIN SomeTable4
        LEFT JOIN SomeTable5
    WHERE --some conditions with string and date functions

    UPDATE @test_table1 SET col1 = 'xyz' WHERE SUBSTRING(col2,1,4) IN ('some values')

    DECLARE @test_table2 TABLE (/*some columns*/);

    WITH [cte1] AS (
        SELECT /*some columns*/ FROM SomeTable1
            INNER JOIN @test_table1 
            LEFT JOIN SomeTable2)
    
    ,[cte2] AS(
        SELECT /*some columns*/ FROM SomeTable1
            INNER JOIN @test_table1 
            LEFT JOIN SomeTable2    
            LEFT JOIN SomeTable3
        UNION
        SELECT /*some columns*/ FROM SomeTable1
            INNER JOIN @test_table1 
            LEFT JOIN SomeTable2    
            LEFT JOIN SomeTable3)
    ,[cte3] AS(
        SELECT DISTINCT /*some columns*/ FROM [cte2]
        WHERE /*some simple conditions*/)

    INSERT INTO @test_table2 
    SELECT /*some columns with string concat using stuff and xml path*/ FROM [cte3]
    GROUP BY /*some columns*/
```

Comment: In SQL Server 2012, the data engine (unfortunately) assumes that a table variable will contain only *one* row. This can lead to some very poor performance due to poor estimates from the data engine. As it appears your table variable(s) contain *many* rows, I wouldn't be surprised if the bad estimates are causing performance issues.

Comment: If you compare the excution plans between the variables/temp tables you'll likely see the issue and as noted it's most likely due to the cardinality estimations. Temp tables are almost always preferable, especially in older SQL Server versions.

Comment: Even 2-3 minutes seems ... ridiculous. What is this query even doing that it takes more than a few seconds no matter what type of temp object you're using? What happens if you eliminate temp objects period?

Comment: Bad query is a bad query. You don't have to use every sql server operator per query, also, you don't have to cram everything into one statement. Finally, UNIONs instead of UNION ALLs combined with DISTINCT is usually a sign that something went bad along the way. Try to simplify the whole thing

Comment: All, I am not looking for comments about query that is good/bad. I know this is not the right way of writing a query and I am not it's author. What I am more interested is why a table variable is extremely slow in this case when compared to temporary table. I am comparing the execution plan of both the cases and will update if I find anything valuable.

Comment: Can you show how you declare / set the temporary table?

Comment: @YairMaron - It is in the first line of the code.

Comment: @Madhukar, it doesn't look like a temporary table... it is a table variable

Comment: @YairMaron - Sorry! I thought you asked table variable. Temp tables used here also have similar syntax. CREATE TABLE #temp (/*some columns#/)

Comment: if you don't show the plan or any real details, i think i'd rather vote on closing the question, @ThomA's answer is probably as good as it can get, temp variables have different cardinality (number of rows) than ev. temporary tables so the engine chooses different query plan, case closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Table variables are kept in the RAM, making all access to it very fast
while temporary tables are physically created on the disk."

Every time someone goes to me to ask why temporary tables can actually show better performance than table variables I hear some variation of that quote.

So I must remember people the engine makes lots of estimates and assumptions even when trying to fetch data from the most simple query. One of those most important estimates is about the size of the returned dataset.
Most of the time those table variables' bad performance is due to the dataset returning a lot of data, more than the engine is willing to take from the RAM
and starts using the disk, exactly the same temp used by temporary tables.

So why worse and not the same performance?
Table variables are supposed to be small, very small indeed and most importantly, smaller than the "equivalent"/"default" temporary table.
While the dataset size increases, the engine must reallocate more and more disk space and make more and more page splits and stuff and thanks to all those initial assumptions the overhead for table variables is a lot worse.

That's why my advice to anyone trying to use tables variables or temporary tables is: Have you tested the other way around?

The TOP 100 also can be misleading, it means only you want to SHOW UP THE FIRST 100, but that doesn't imply the engine doesn't need to retrieve entire tables to apply a sort on a big mess of data. All at the expense of the initial reserved memory space

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen regarding this topic